# sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats and last_user_scan always NULL

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm looking at various scripts used to find missing indexes in SQL Server, and they all usually/always use sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats

Everything is good, except for the user_scans and last_user_scan columns:
user_scans always appears to be 0, and last_user_scan is always NULL

I have tried this across multiple SQL Server databases, on multiple different versions of SQL Server and I cannot find a single case where I can find non-zero/non-NULL values in these two columns.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Speculation: the current version of the engine simply doesn't track if an index could have been useful for a scan alone and only kicks in if an inefficient scan is used that could have been improved by a seek. It's much easier to spot that case than recommending a better index for scanning, anyway (and it over-recommends indexes as it is).

Comment: Maybe user_scans will always be 0 and last_user_scan will always be null because such scans would be answered by a Clustered Index scan or a Table Scan (in the case of a heap)? I expect those columns exist because they previously existed in the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats DMV and were copied without a good reason.